# Cosine Distance and Recommender Systems

Tags: recommender-system

Suppose that a computer is rated according to three numerical features: processor speed, disk size, main-memory size. Consider three computers $A,B$ and $C$ with values: $$A(3.06,500,6)$$ $$B(2.68, 320,4)$$ $$C(2.92,640,6)$$

The cosine distance emphasizes differences in disk size more than differences in other features. What is the interpretation of the angle between the normalized vectors? If we normalize the vectors, than the cosine distance can take values between $0^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$. If we do not normalize the vectors, then the cosine distance can take values between $0^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: How did you normalize the vectors? Show the new values.

Comment: Those are on different numerical scales, so they won't make sense. But if you really want to interpret, cosine distance on raw numbers will emphasize larger numbers. On scaled numbers, it will emphasize variables with higher standard deviation (roughly but not strictly true).